# Existence of a special type of injective function $f:A \to \mathbb R$ , where $A \subseteq \mathbb R$ is uncountable

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Does there exist an uncountable subset  $A \subseteq\mathbb R$ such that there exist an injective function $f:A \to \mathbb R$ such that for every $a \in A$ , there exist a connected subset $S \subseteq \mathbb R$ with more than one point such that $\{a\}=f^{-1}(S)$ ? Can $f$ be continuous ?

Comment: Your question puts no condition on $S$. Do you mean $\{a\}=f^{-1}(S)$ perhaps?

Comment: @LeeMosher : Yes , it is $S$ ; corrected

Comment: @bburGsamohT: by definition, $f^{-1}(S) = \{x \in A \bigm| f(x) \in S\}$.

Comment: @user228169 Ah shoot I always forget about when you need to invoke surjectivity and all that. Sorry.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. $f^{-1}(S)$ can't have lower cardinality than $S$, but $\{a\}$ has only one element and $S$ at least two, so $f^{-1}(S)$ must have at least two elements which forbids it being equal to $\{a\}$.

Comment: @skyking: $f^{-1}(S)$ can't have lower cardinality than $S \cap f(A)$, but it certainly can have lower cardinality than $S$.

Comment: Note that this question can be made simpler by passing from $A$ to $f(A)$: you're asking whether there is an uncountable set of reals, all of whose elements are isolated (in the usual topology). By the way, it's worth noting that if you weaken this slightly the answer becomes *yes*: there are uncountable sets of reals which are *nowhere dense*, that is, for every point $x$ and every neighborhood $U\ni x$ there is a nontrivial open interval $V\subseteq U$ which is disjoint from the set.

Comment: @LeeMosher How can $f^{-1}(S)$ have lower cardinality than $S$? By selecting an $x=\phi(y)$ such that $f(x)=y$ we have created an injection from $S$ to $f^{-1}(S)$.

Answer (score 2):

No such setup exists. Here is an argument by contradiction.

We may assume $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is inclusion.

Assume by contradiction that for each $a \in A$ there is an interval $S_a \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $S_a \cap A = \{a\}$. We may assume, by truncating $S_a$ if necessary, that $a$ is an endpoint of $S_a$. Choose $S'_a$ to be a subinterval of $S_a$ with endpoint $a$ such that 
$$0 < \text{Length}(S'_a) \le \frac{1}{2} \text{Length}(S_a)
$$
It follows that if $a \ne b \in A$ then $S'_a \cap S'_b = \emptyset$. Choose a rational number $r_a \in S'_a$. Then the function $a \mapsto r_a$ is an injective function $A \mapsto \mathbb{Q}$, and therefore $A$ is countable.